# Accessing entity attributes in twig after using DataTransformer in a Form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I´ve the following code to create a custom form type that transforms an entity to id in order to create an autocomplete field.

```
class EntityIdType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new EntityIdTransformer($this->em,$options['entity_class']);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }
}
```

I have also created a custom widget to this form type and I want to get the string that represents that entity on it

```
{% block entity_id_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <input type="hidden" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
        <input autocomplete="off" value="{{ **GET_VALUE_HERE** }}">
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE**

The EntityIdTransformer's transform method just returns the entity's id and reverse transform returns the entity associated to the id passed as parameter

The goal of all this is to create an autocomplete input for an entity with many rows and persist the changes when submiting the form. If any other approach could be better for this example I will apreciate it.

It seems that an `entity_identifier` field type has been added as a proposal in a PR but doesnt seem to be available in near future yet

Comment: What is your question? Where is the code of that data transformer? What have you tried?

Comment: @byf-ferdy I've updated the question with more info. I think autocompleting entities is quite common but I didnt come across any good solution better than using data transformers. It works good in general but I dont know how to get the string related to each entity, I can only get the Id of the entity because of the data transformer when I render the widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to get the string returning an array from the DataTransformer with an id and a string describing the entity

```
public function transform($entity)
{
    if (null === $entity) {
        return "";
    }

    return array("id" => $entity->getId(), "name" => $entity->__toString());
}
```

While rendering my custom widget now I can access to those values like this

```
{% block entity_id_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <input type="hidden" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value.id }}" {% endif %}/>
    <input class="blocked" autocomplete="off" {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value.name }}" {% endif %}>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: After searching for hours I ended up doing the same thing. It's a pity you can't access the entity itself from within the form - after all it **already** has loaded the entity and the result.